# How can you create an iCloud Calender for an iOS app to use with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen many people simply search the user's calendars and then grab the first one that's writable and start throwing the events on there. I don't like this practice; I prefer to respect my users a little more.

So how can you actually make your own calendar for the app to use for the events that it creates?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following function, assuming your app is allowed to access the users calendars:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

func checkCalendar() -> EKCalendar {
    var retCal: EKCalendar?

    let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) as! [EKCalendar] // Grab every calendar the user has
    var exists: Bool = false
    for calendar in calendars { // Search all these calendars
        if calendar.title == "Any String" {
            exists = true
            retCal = calendar
        }
    }

    var err : NSError?
    if !exists {
        let newCalendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent, eventStore:eventStore)
        newCalendar.title="Any String"
        newCalendar.source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source
        eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit:true, error:&err)
        retCal = newCalendar
    }

    return retCal!

}
```

This function looks for a calendar by the name of "Any String". Of course, this can be anything you like. If it doesn't exist, it will create it. It then returns the calendar, so you can assign it to a calendar variable and then work with it however you please.

Comment: @weePee This method automatically makes it an iCloud Calendar.